# Is there a scaling behavior guide for designing sites & system interfaces?

Tags: responsive-design, scaling, size

In my work I was asked to define the scaling behavior of the system interface (or website), and I was wondering whether there are any guidelines or best practices  about how to characterize and design the scaling behaviors of different elements on the screen?

for example i`m planning a system with left navigation panel, menu header and main dashboard panel with tabels,forms and graphs. for this system i would like to define the best behavior of each panel. by that i mean, if the user resize the system window, how will the different element will change according to the screen size. should the width porportion of the navigation panel need to remain the same (fixed)? and so on for the other panels

Comment: Hi Shai, welcome to UX! Could you try being more specific? What kind of website are you trying to scale? Why?

Comment: Thanks! i looking for general gudieline. for example i`m planning a system with left navigation panel, menu header and main dashboard panel with tabels,forms and graphs. for this system i would like to define the best behavior of each panel. by that i mean, if the user resize the system window, how will the different element will change according to the screen size. should the width porportion of the navigation panel need to remain the same? and so on for the other panels

Comment: Shai - please edit this information into your question. There's a link just under the tags or [use this one](http://ux.stackexchange.com/posts/16537/edit)

Comment: Shai, I don’t believe you will ever be able to get general guidelines that will be universal to all projects. These are the types of parameters that need to be set on a project-by-project basis depending on the requirements. Also, this is more of a front-end development question rather than related to UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but it might point you in the right direction. http://uxmag.com/articles/framework-for-designing-for-multiple-devices. It suggests how to create a framework for designing for different screen sizes.